# OSClass a lot of item adding at once

Tags: php, osclass

So my task is to create a button in the advertisments part of osclass web page. Were an authenticated user could press a button "add more" and then choice any amount of pictures for example 30. And then those pictures would be counted as a separate advertisement. Then the user could add some detail to each one of the advertisements. As I have never created a plug-in for osclass I would like some guidance/help in doing so. Any links of good tutorials that could help me accomplish this would be great! And thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tutorial to help you [develop a plugin for Osclass](https://wearemadhouse.wordpress.com/2013/10/11/how-to-develop-osclass-plugins/). :)

About the plugin you want to create, it seems you want to create a custom attributes plugin (extra fields added to items) to extend Osclass item datas.